# How to use a variable from a dataframe in a function that uses formulas in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, formula

I am trying to create a function, that runs a t-test for whatever variable I give it as an argument.

To demonstration purposes i just added, another column to the toothgrowth data frame, because my original data frame is way too big.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix) 
library(ggpubr)
df <- ToothGrowth
df$width <- runif(60, min = 5, max = 10)
```

I tried to generalise a method i found on [Datanovia](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-add-p-values-onto-a-grouped-ggplot-using-the-ggpubr-r-package/) which creates a grouped box plot like this [Grouped Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3aXL.png). So I tried to generalise the code into a function:

```
plotStats <- function(var) {
stat.test <- df %>% group_by(supp) %>% t_test(.data[[var]] ~ dose)
stat.test
}
```

However, was my own and this demonstration df i get the error message:
Can't extract columns that don't exist. x The column `.data[[var]] doesn't exist.

I am using this method, because further down the road I am extracting the p-values for plots in exploratory data analysis.

This would be somehow the function i'd love to work:

```
plotStats <- function(var) {
stat.test <- df %>% group_by(supp) %>% t_test(.data[[var]] ~ dose)
stat.test <- stat.test %>% 
  add_xy_position(x = "supp", dodge = 0.8)

ggplot(stats, aes(supp, .data[[var]])) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = dose)) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(
    stat.test, label = "p.adj",tip.length = 0.01,
    bracket.nudge.y = -2
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1)))
}

plotStats(var = "len")
plotStats(var = "width")
```

I think the problem might be in the usage of formulas within functions but can't seem to figure a way out to make it work.

Any help is appreciated.
Kind regards
Max

Comment: `library(tidyverse, rstatix, ggpubr)` isn’t valid. For some reason R doesn’t throw an error but nevertheless it doesn’t work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I get an error (tried with dplyr instead if tidyverse).

Comment: @Roland It works if the package is already loaded, or if you only specify two arguments.

Comment: Hi Konrad and Roland, i fixed it to install.packages. It should work now!

Comment: @portablemaex no, `install.packages` installs but doesn't load packages, and it doesn't take unquoted names like that. You will find this causes an error - something like "object 'tidyverse' not found". Just change `install.packages` back to `library` in each of  the three separate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here. The main one is getting the non-standard evaluation correct. It would be nice to pass unquoted column names to the function. You can capture these with `rlang::ensym`. You can use that to build a formula which you pass to `t_test` (and later to `facet_grid`). You can also use these captured variable names to pass to ggplot using the double bang (`!!`) operator.

A more general observation is that it would be preferable to have your function generalized so that it works on other data sets, so remove the hard-coded data frame and variable names inside the function. Just pass in the ones that you use.

A general function to produce the type of plot you are looking for would then look something like this:

```r
plotStats <- function(df, var1, var2, var3) 
{
  var1 <- ensym(var1)
  var2 <- ensym(var2)
  var3 <- ensym(var3)
  
  f <- as.formula(paste(as.character(var2), "~", as.character(var3)))
  fac <- as.formula(paste("~", as.character(var1)))
  stat.test <- df %>% 
                 group_by(!!var1) %>% 
                 t_test(f) %>%
                 add_xy_position(step.increase = 0.5)
  
  ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(!!var3), y = !!var2, fill = factor(!!var3))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.5, 0.5)) +
    facet_grid(fac, switch = "x") +
    geom_bracket(data = stat.test, inherit.aes = FALSE,
                 aes(xmin = group1, xmax = group2, label = p)) +
    labs(fill = as.character(var3), x = as.character(var1)) +
    theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"),
          strip.placement = "outside",
          strip.background = element_blank()) 
}
```

Allowing:

```r
plotStats(df, supp, width, dose)
```

[image]

and

```r
plotStats(df, supp, len, dose)
```

[image]

And you can apply it other data frames:

```r
plotStats(mtcars, cyl, wt, am)
```

[image]

I'll leave it up to you to adjust the step increase, fill colours and themes to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi Allan, this is great! As I am new to programming, I always try to figure things out the easiest way for me - not thinking about other data frames... But I get your point and will try to implement it in the future!
What exactly does the step increase do and how does it work? I played a bit with it, but on different data frames the same step increase is handled differently..

P.S. the approach to using ensym to use unquoted columns is also really nice. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make this work. It builds a formula object using your `var` argument. Also, it is good practice to pass all objects/variables needed by a function in as arguments (in other words not letting the function relying on something saved in the global environment).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
plotStats <- function(df, var) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste(var, "~", "dose"))
  stat.test <-  t_test(data = df %>% group_by(supp), formula)
  stat.test
}

plotStats(df, "width")
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  supp  .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic    df     p p.adj p.adj.signif
* <fct> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
1 OJ    width 0.5    1         10    10    0.398   17.4 0.695     1 ns          
2 OJ    width 0.5    2         10    10   -0.114   15.0 0.911     1 ns          
3 OJ    width 1      2         10    10   -0.415   16.5 0.683     1 ns          
4 VC    width 0.5    1         10    10   -0.664   16.1 0.516     1 ns          
5 VC    width 0.5    2         10    10   -0.0830  16.2 0.935     1 ns          
6 VC    width 1      2         10    10    0.503   18.0 0.621     1 ns   

plotStats(df, "len")
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  supp  .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic    df            p      p.adj p.adj.signif
* <fct> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>       
1 OJ    len   0.5    1         10    10     -5.05  17.7 0.0000878    0.000176   ***         
2 OJ    len   0.5    2         10    10     -7.82  14.7 0.00000132   0.00000396 ****        
3 OJ    len   1      2         10    10     -2.25  15.8 0.039        0.039      *           
4 VC    len   0.5    1         10    10     -7.46  17.9 0.000000681  0.00000136 ****        
5 VC    len   0.5    2         10    10    -10.4   14.3 0.0000000468 0.00000014 ****        
6 VC    len   1      2         10    10     -5.47  13.6 0.0000916    0.0000916  ****
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks a lot. This is working great. Even better, it also works with my data frame. Any idea why my approach wasn't working? Must be some formula related issue, or am i thinking in the wrong direction? Sorry for the maybe dumb question, but quite new to R and Programming in general...

Comment: Formula objects don't handle character inputs or column subsets. Building the formula object ahead of time solves this issue.